# Sklearn: What is the equivalent of check_estimator for TransformerMixin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm trying to create a custom feature extractor using `FunctionTransformer` for personal use. I'd like to make it as compliant with the scikit-learn API as possible to avoid warnings and errors down the line, but I can't get it to pass the `check_estimator` test.

However, I noticed that a provided feature extractor, `DictVectorizer` doesn't pass the test either despite being a child of `BaseEstimator`. My understanding is that the `TransformerMixin` seems to be causing the issue.

```
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
check_estimator(LinearSVC)  # passes

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
check_estimator(DictVectorizer)  # fails
```

Is there an equivalent of `check_estimator` that works with `TransformerMixin`?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Its not a estimator. Its a transformer, so may not pass the test. You can try `check_transformer_general()`

Comment: Thank you, I checked it out! It looks like the checks for transformers are less stringent because of the variability of input data.